# Alternative of multiple args parameter

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am working on a design, where I am using var argument. Now the problem is I need to use two different type of var arguments.

method signature

```
void addInformation(
    final String call,
    final ApiEnum... apis,
    final ApiTypes... types);
```

As this is not possible. What could be a better alternative to this design.

Comment: Alternatively, a builder pattern-esque approach would allow for as many varargs as you want.

Answer (score 0):

this may help:

```
class ApiModel {
    ApiEnum api;
    ApiTypes type;
}
void addInformation(String call, ApiModel... args)
```

but, varargs is a compromise.

Comment: This can be a solution if   ApiEnum and  ApiType go in pairs.